# Additional order email based on custom customer field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

I need to send a copy of the order email to a second email adress defined by a custom field.

I have installed the iconic custom account field plugin and created a custom field on the user (I works and I can edit it in admin). 
https://iconicwp.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-adding-custom-woocommerce-user-account-fields/
It's named 'iconic-register-email'

I have also implemented this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92020/adding-a-second-email-address-to-a-completed-order-in-woocommerce solution to send an extra email. It works with a hard-coded email.

Now I need to combine the solutions and I just can't get it to work. I have appended the send email code at the bottom of the iconic plugin code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'mycustom_headers_filter_function', 10, 2);
function mycustom_headers_filter_function( $headers, $object ) {

    $sae = 'a-custom-email@gmail.com';

    if ($object == 'customer_completed_order') {
        $headers .=  'BCC: Name <' . $sae . '>' . "\r\n";
    }

    return $headers;
}
```

This code works, but I need to use iconic-register-email field.

Need to fetch the registred email adress on a user, so when that user makes an order an order copy is sent to that adress defined by iconic-register-email.

My knowledge about coding is very limited, please help. Last thing to add before I can go live.

Comment: I'm about to start crying. Just can't get any value out :(
$sae = iconic_get_userdata( $user_id, 'iconic-register-email' );
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it. Not sure if it's the most elegant solution, but it works.

As it's predefined functions and arrays, this is how I did it

```
function mycustom_headers_filter_function( $headers, $object ) {
    $sae = iconic_get_userdata( get_current_user_id(), 'iconic-register-email' );

    if ($object == 'new_order') {
        $headers .=  'BCC: <' . $sae . '>' . "\r\n";
    }

    return $headers;
}
```